# Nice Answer Badge Bug?

Tags: support, badges

I recently got the $10^{th}$ upvote to this answer: [Is there an elementary proof that $\sum \limits_{k=1}^n \frac1k$ is never an integer?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2746/is-there-an-elementary-proof-that-k-1n-1-k-is-never-an-integer/2747#2747)

But got a notification for this answer: [Is there a function with a removable discontinuity at every point?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3777/is-there-a-function-with-a-removable-discontinuity-at-every-point/3802#3802)

There were no upvotes to the latter today.

Here is the image:

[image]

Seems like other folks have hit this bug too, as browsing on meta.stackoverflow.com shows, but posting here as the relevant repro data is on Math.SE.

EDIT: Someone downvoted the answer, so the number of votes is back to 9. The repro has been messed with :-)

Answer (score 2):

Per

https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1102/moron#qpage_1-anpage_1-qsort_votes-ansort_votes

I count THIRTY answers with score >= 10 on page 1, and FIVE on page 2. (I am mentally adding the +1 back for the +9 post.)

That's 35 nice answer badges, which is what you have.

Comment: I am talking about the notification. I got the notification for 3802 twice and none for 2747. The list of answers seems to be wrong too.

Comment: Ok. Someone seems to have downvoted this one too: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3888/find-polynomials-such-that-x-16p2x-16x-1px/3889#3889. This shows up in the list of Nice Answers (that is what I meant in the above comment), but you won't count it when you go by the stats.

Comment: @moron we only match total counts, we don't match specific posts. EG if the count is off, we find a valid post that has not yet been awarded the badge, and award it to that.

Comment: @Jeff: The downvote on 3888 happened _after_ the nice answer badge notification. I saw an upvote on 2747 and a notification of a nice answer for 3802 shortly thereafter. The list of nice answers from my profile page did not list 2747 (before the downvote on it). The timeline seems to be all messed up because of the downvoting! Anyway, I was only reporting a possible bug...

Comment: @moron also, if a post that had 10 votes has BEEN DELETED, this means you are behind a badge and you won't get the next one because the counts are off.

Comment: @jeff: I have no clue if a post has been deleted. Anyway, you are free to delete this thread if it is not really a bug...